# Cannot call Close when Closing event is override

Tags: c#, wpf

In my `MainWindow` constructor I ovverided the `Closing` event because I need to call another method that perform some task, like:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Closing += (x, y) =>
        {
            y.Cancel = true;
            _discard = true;
            CheckSettings();
        };
    }

    public void CheckSettings(bool x)
    {
       if(x)
         Close(); 
    }
```

on the `Close` line I get:

> cannot set visibility or call show or showdialog after window has closed

why??

Comment: You cannot call `Close` from a Closing event handler. You probably need to let `CheckSettings` return a bool, use its return value to set `y.Cancel`, and remove the `Close` call from `CheckSettings`

Comment: Closing a window while it's being closed is not meaningful, and would also cause an infinite loop if the framework didn't do anything special to detect it. Rather than ask "why is it giving an error", you should ask yourself why you're doing this.

Comment: @vc74 could  you show an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(as requested in you comment...)
You cannot call Close from a Closing event handler.

If the logic determining if the form can be closed is implemented in `CheckSettings`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Closing += (sender, args) =>
    {
        args.Cancel = !CheckSettings();
        ...
    };
}

public bool CheckSettings()
{
   // Check and return true if the form can be closed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Until you return from your event handler (that's made the call to `CheckSettings`), the UI framework you're using may not evaluate the content of the `EventArgs` that you've named as `y` and set `Cancel = true` on.

If you're using WPF, for example, the `Close` method eventually calls down into another method called [`VerifyNotClosing`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,08803a2385930d32) (via `InternalClose`) which at the time of writing looks like this:

```
private void VerifyNotClosing()
{
    if (_isClosing == true)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.InvalidOperationDuringClosing));
    }

    if (IsSourceWindowNull == false && IsCompositionTargetInvalid == true)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.InvalidCompositionTarget));
    }
}
```

The relevant bit there is the first `if` that checks a member variable called `_isClosing` and throws an exception if the form is in the process of closing.
The `InternalClose` method reacts to the state of the `Cancel` property of the EventArgs **after** the event handlers have been called:

```
CancelEventArgs e = new CancelEventArgs(false);
try
{
    // The event handler is called here
    OnClosing(e);
}
catch
{
    CloseWindowBeforeShow();
    throw;
}

// The status of the .Cancel on the EventArgs is not checked until here
if (ShouldCloseWindow(e.Cancel))
{
    CloseWindowBeforeShow();
}
else
{
    _isClosing = false;
    // 03/14/2006 -- hamidm
    // WOSB 1560557 Dialog does not close with ESC key after it has been cancelled
    //
    // No need to reset DialogResult to null here since source window is null.  That means
    // that ShowDialog has not been called and thus no need to worry about DialogResult.
}
```

The code above (from the [`InternalClose`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,25d7e5b48381f32f,references) method) is *after* the call to `VerifyNotClosing` which is why the subsequent call to `Close`, before the first one has finished, results in the exception being thrown.